# Is there a way to change the DLL reference version in C++/CLI net framework 4.6.2 project?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a net framework 4.6.2 C++/CLI project. This project references mscorelib, System.Core, and System. The reference path is

```
..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\mscorlib.dll

..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.dll
..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Core.dll
```

It contains a number of namespaces. Here are a few of them

```
System.Runtime.Extensions (4.0.10.0)
System.Runtime.InteropServices(4.0.20.0)
System.Reflection(4.0.10.0)
System.Linq.Expressions(4.0.10.0)
System.IO (4.0.10.0)
System.Globalization(4.0.10.0)
System.Dynamic.Runtime (4.0.10.0)
System.Diagnostics.Debug (4.0.10.0)
System.Diagnostics.Tracing (4.0.20.0)
System.ComponentModel.Annotations (4.0.10.0)
System.Collections.Concurrent (4.0.10.0)
System.Runtime (4.0.20.0)
```

I have a second project in C# netstandard 1.5. This project also have the same references as in the first project, but in version 4.1.0.0.

I have a third project in C# net framework 4.6.2 referencing both first and second projects.

There are a lot of warning messages while compiling the third project. The code compiled successfully, asked me to fix the warnings.

The warning messages are

```
     No way to resolve conflict between "System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
     No way to resolve conflict between "System.IO, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.IO, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.IO, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
    No way to resolve conflict between "System.Reflection, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Reflection, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Reflection, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
    No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
     No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
      No way to resolve conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60". Choosing "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" arbitrarily.
     No way to resolve conflict between "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60". Choosing "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" arbitrarily.
     No way to resolve conflict between "Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60". Choosing "Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" arbitrarily.
      No way to resolve conflict between "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60". Choosing "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" arbitrarily.
     No way to resolve conflict between "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" and "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51". Choosing "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" arbitrarily.
     No way to resolve conflict between "System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.1.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
      No way to resolve conflict between "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed". Choosing "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" arbitrarily.
```

Is there a way to change the reference version of C++/CLI project to a higher version (from version 4.0.10.0 to 4.1.0.0)?

Comment: Please show a sampling of the error messages. Also, how are your doing your build, through Visual Studio, MSBuild?

Comment: As clarification, an assembly contains types, not namespaces. Namespaces don't have owners or versions. A namespace is just part of the name of a type.

Comment: I displayed the warning messages. It was complied in Visual studio 2017. It should be MS build. You are right. It should be called class types.

Comment: You are wasting your time, a C++/CLI assembly can only ever run on the full version of .NET.  So there is no point whatsoever in using .NETStandard or .NETCore reference assemblies.

Comment: Everything works fine except for the warning messages.